# std::function to variadic member function and then bind variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, std-function, stdbind

I have two variadic class member functions. 
When the first one `Init(...)` is called I want to create a std::function to the second class member function and then bind the arguments of `Init(...)` to the function pointer.

So then later on I can just call `mf_()` without having to pass all arguments to `Reset(...)` again

I'd like to avoid making it template class and store the arguments in a tuple.

I'm trying to make the following example work :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename... T>
    void Init(T&... args)
    {
        cout << __func__ << endl;
        Print(args...);

        // bind args.. to Reset ..
        mf_ = std::bind(&Reset, args...);
       // mf_ = std::bind(&Foo::Reset, this, args...); ???
    }

    template<typename... T>
    void Reset(T&... args)
    {
        cout << __func__ << endl;
    }

    // std::function to Reset(...)
    std::function<void()> mf_;

private:
    template<typename First>
    void Print(First& arg)
    {
        cout << arg << endl;
    }

    template<typename First, typename... Rest>
    void Print(First& arg, Rest&... args)
    {
        cout << arg << " ";
        Print(args...);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    int arg1 = 1;
    int arg2 = 2;
    string arg3 { "test" };
    double arg4 = 1.10;

    Foo foo;
    foo.Init(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);

    //foo.mf_();
    return 0;
}
```

Link to live example : http://cpp.sh/4ylm

When I compile I get an error that states

> template argument deduction/substitution failed: 17:37:
>   note: couldn't deduce template parameter '_Result'

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `&Reset` is not a valid pointer-to-member expression.

You need to say `&Foo::Reset` to form a pointer-to-member function, and you also need to supply the `this` pointer, so you're almost correct with:

```
   // mf_ = std::bind(&Foo::Reset, this, args...); ???
```

But it's still not valid because `Reset` is a function template and so you need to say which specialization of the template you mean.

You can tell the compiler which specialization you want by providing an explicit template argument list:

```
mf_ = std::bind(&Foo::Reset<T&...>, this, args...);
```

Or by creating a variable of the right type, initialized from `&Foo::Reset`, which allows the compiler to deduce which specialization you mean:

```
void (Foo::*f)(T&...) = &Foo::Reset;
mf_ = std::bind(f, this, args...);
```

Or by creating a typedef for the right type, and casting `&Foo::Reset` to that type:

```
   using pmf_type = void (Foo::*)(T&...);
   mf_ = std::bind((pmf_type)&Foo::Reset, this, args...);
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working. Updated my original question with a live solution demo